# ProTip: Very Important thing to remember when using QScrollArea

Tags: qt, pyqt4

Today I spent 3 hours in figuring why my `QScrollArea` was not working. And finally found that the reason was the components which I was dynamically adding to the ScrollArea didn't have any Layout so it was not able to compute the minimum size of it while adding. 
So If anyone is adding elements dynamically to the QScrollArea, make sure your widgets have some area. I saw lot of posts where people where facing the same issue and there was no direct answer that layout is the cause so this is like a post notifying to the all users to make sure you first have a layout in all of your widgets you want to append to QScrollArea.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An example would be

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic


mainBase, mainForm = uic.loadUiType("main.ui")
labelBase, labelForm = uic.loadUiType("labelsForScroll.ui")
dataBase, dataForm = uic.loadUiType("data.ui")
emptyBase, emptyForm = uic.loadUiType("empty.ui")

class Data(dataBase, dataForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataBase, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setSl(self, num):
        self.sl.setText(str(num))

class Label(labelBase, labelForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(labelBase, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Empty(emptyBase, emptyForm):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(emptyBase, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class Main(mainBase, mainForm):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainBase, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.__l = Label()
        #self.vert.addWidget(l)
        self.__maxSlNum = 0
        self.__datLis =[]
        #self.addField()
        self.__e = Empty()
        self.__e.layout().addWidget(self.__l)

        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.__e)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.add, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.addField)




    def addField(self):
        d = Data()
        self.__maxSlNum+=1
        d.setSl(self.__maxSlNum)
        self.__datLis.append(d)
        lay = self.__e.layout()
        lay.addWidget( d)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("cleanlooks")
    m = Main()
    m.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

links for the ui file can be found here [links](http://1drv.ms/1QZPjZc)

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47656/can-i-post-tips-instead-of-questions and maybe you can avoid mad voters

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: I know but I kept this as a tip  so that other's can benefit from it.